# How can I add r'"' to each line of a file if it doesn't end with r'"'

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, encoding, carriage-return

I want to have each line of a `.txt` file to end with `"`, but the coding of file is `gb2312` or `gbk`, since Chinese is include. So I create a file named `heheda.txt`, whose content is as follows (the end of each line contains a return):

```
从前有座山"
shan里有个庙
"庙里有个"
laohe尚
```

Then what I tried is as follows:

```
for line in open('heheda.txt', 'r'):
    if not line[-2] == r'"':
        print line
        line = line[:-1] + r'"' + line[-1:]
        print line
```

and it returns:

```
shan里有个庙

shan里有个庙"

laohe尚
laohe�"�
```

I don't know why end for each line is `line[-2]`, since I have tried `line.endswith(r'"')` and `line[-1] == r'"'`. And the first sentence get the right format, while second sentence with something wrong (`�`).

Then I tried to read in binary mode with `rb`, which makes me surprises me again:

```
a_file = open(data_path+'heheda.txt', 'rb')
for line in a_file:
    if line[-3] != r'"':
        print line
        line = line[:-2] + r'"' + line[-2:]
        print line
```

and it returns:

```
shan里有个庙

shan里有个庙"

laohe尚
laohe�"��
```

This time, I have to use `line[-3] != r'"'` as the condition to judge whether sentence end with `"` or not.
I cannot figure out what happens.
By the way I work in Windows7 with python 2.7.11

Does anyone know what's going on??

Comment: To see better what is happening, use print repr(line) instead of print line

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of `repr()` which let me know what really happens!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows uses `"\r\n"` as newline which is automatically translated to `"\n"` with text-reading mode. But your last line has no newline character.

Just strip newline characters and then test for `"`:

```
with open('heheda.txt', 'r') as lines:
    for line in lines:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if not line.endswith('"'):
            line += '"'
        print line
```

Comment: Windows uses \r\n, not \n\r

Comment: After using `repr()`, I find last line just end with no `\r\n` as you said. And `rstrip()` can filter '\r\n', `\t` in the end of a string, it's amazing!